# SUMIFS Formula in VBA with "<"

Tags: vba, excel, sumifs

Please could you tell me what is wrong with my second last `SUMIFS` formula where I use `" < " &$F$1`. All that is returned is FALSE in all the cells. The last SUMIFS without the < works fine.

```
Sub SumGroups()

Worksheets("Database").Activate
Dim lastCode, lastFiltCode As Integer
Dim Formula As String

'Determine Last Row in Column O (Unfiltered Codes)
lastCode = Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Filter Unique Codes into Column A Sheet2
Range("O1:O" & lastCode).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
      CopyToRange:=Sheet2.Range("A1"), Unique:=True
'Determine last Row in Column A (Filtered Codes)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
lastFiltCode = Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Place SUMIF Formulas in Columns Sheet2    
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B" & lastFiltCode).Formula = _
"=SUMIFS(Database!$M$2:$M$" & lastCode & ",Database!$O$2:$O$" & lastCode & ",A2)"
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D2:D" & lastFiltCode).Formula = _
"=SUMIFS(Database!$M$2:$M$" & lastCode & ",Database!$O$2:$O$" & lastCode & ",A2,Database!$I$2:$I$" & lastCode & "," < " &$F$1)"
 Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F2:F" & lastFiltCode).Formula = _
"=SUMIFS(Database!$M$2:$M$" & lastCode & ",Database!$O$2:$O$" & lastCode & ",A2,Database!$I$2:$I$" & lastCode & ",$F$1)"

End Sub
```

Comment: beside that you have a lot of unnecessary `Select` and  `Activate`

Comment: Range $I$2:$I$ are dates and Cell$F$1 is a date,

Comment: Hi Shai, When I try < $F$1)  I receive Run-Time error '1004': Application-defined or Object-defined error. Appreciate your time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in order to get `<$F$1` inside the formula I use the `Chr(34)` to add the parenthesis `"`" inside the formula.

Besides that, you are mixing-up a few things:

- Try to avoid using `Worksheets("Database").Activate` and `Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate`, and instead use fully qualified worksheets and ranges, like: `With Worksheets("Database")` and inside `lastCode = .Range("O" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`.
- You have `Sheet2` and `Worksheets("Sheet2")`, these two not always mean the same worksheet. You could rename `Sheet2` (by code name) to "Something", and that will be your 2nd sheet, and rename `Sheet3` (by code name) to "Sheet2" and you have a problem. So decide on which method you want to use (I prefer to use `Worksheets("Sheet2")`).
- `Dim lastCode, lastFiltCode As Integer` means `lastCode` is actually `Variant` and `lastFiltCode` is `Integer`. Anyway, it's better to use `Long` for both of these variables when you are trying to get the last row.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SumGroups()

Dim lastCode As Long, lastFiltCode As Long

'Determine Last Row in Column O (Unfiltered Codes)
With Worksheets("Database")
    lastCode = .Range("O" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Filter Unique Codes into Column A Sheet2
    .Range("O1:O" & lastCode).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CopyToRange:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1"), Unique:=True        
End With

With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    'Determine last Row in Column A (Filtered Codes)
    lastFiltCode = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Place SUMIF Formulas in Columns Sheet2
    .Range("B2:B" & lastFiltCode).Formula = _
        "=SUMIFS(Database!$M$2:$M$" & lastCode & ",Database!$O$2:$O$" & lastCode & ",A2)"

    .Range("D2:D" & lastFiltCode).Formula = _
        "=SUMIFS(Database!$M$2:$M$" & lastCode & ",Database!$O$2:$O$" & lastCode & ",A2,Database!$I$2:$I$" & lastCode & "," & Chr(34) & "<" & Chr(34) & "&$F$1)"

    .Range("F2:F" & lastFiltCode).Formula = _
        "=SUMIFS(Database!$M$2:$M$" & lastCode & ",Database!$O$2:$O$" & lastCode & ",A2,Database!$I$2:$I$" & lastCode & ",$F$1)"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips Shai Rado

Comment: @Anthony you might want to mark as "Answer" one of the answers you got here (and/or upvote)

Comment: Hi Shai Rado, I am new on this site. I clicked on the ^ arrow. Hopefully I have done the right thing.

Comment: that's upvote, to mark as "Answer" you need to click on the **V** next to one of the answers (you will see the **V** turns green), and it will also raise your point +2

Comment: Ok clicked on the V. Hope all is good. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: @Anthony no you didn't none of the answers (mine or M Omar) **V** is green

Comment: Aah.. It is the tick I must click.

Comment: @Anthony  LOL, congrats , you did it

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify why the other answers work:

SumIfs (as well as various other Excel functions requiring string operators (such as CountIf) expect that logical operators and their following statements be expressed as a string. I.e. should be enclosed in speech marks e.g. "myString".

Since a formula is also a string e.g. `ActiveCell.Formula = "=If(A1=3, 1, 0)"` the compiler gets confused about which set of quotation marks denotes the string. So for example this will not work: `ActiveCell.Formula = "=If(A1=3, "Yes", "No")"`.

Technically the way to deal with this is to enclose the required quotation mark in quotation marks of it own; `""" myValue """`.

However, this quickly becomes confusing. Instead, use the [Character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264465.aspx) function to return the char you require. In this case 34; `chr(34) & myvalue & (chr34)`.

Comment: nice explanation , that's why I prefer to use `Chr(34)` instead of counting how many `"` I have

Answer (score 1):

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D2:D" & lastFiltCode).Formula = _
"=SUMIFS(Database!$M$2:$M$" & lastCode & ",Database!$O$2:$O$" & lastCode &      ",A2,Database!$I$2:$I$" & lastCode & ","" < "" &$F$1)"
```

This will do it.
put < in quotes.

Comment: Thank you the double quotes work! M Omar you are a scholar and a gentleman / lady.